# React JS: Correct way to redirect from one component to another on URL click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, crud

Okay, so I'm totally new with React JS and I'm trying to follow some tutorials online. I've created the CRUD api's and hosted it in Azure. The api's are working. However, my problem is with the Frontend framework. I choses React JS so I can learn it.

I am trying to setup my project to allow CRUD operations. I'm having problems redirecting the user from the list of **Products/Items** to the **Add New Item** page when **AddNewItem** url is clicked

Here's what I have so far

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';

import {Home} from './components/Home';
import {Products} from './components/Products';
import {NoMatch} from './components/NoMatch';
import {Layout} from './components/Layout';
import {NavigationBar} from './components/NavigationBar';    

class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <NavigationBar/>
      <Layout>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/products" component={Products} />
          <Route component={NoMatch} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
      </Layout>
    </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Product.js**

```
import Items from './Items';
import AddNewItem from './AddNewItem';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import React, { Component } from 'react';


export const Products = () => (
    <div>
        <br />
        <h2>All Products</h2>
        <Link to={"./AddNewItem"} className="btn btn-primary">
        Add Item
        </Link>
        <Items/>
    </div>
);
```

**Items.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Table, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';


class Items extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: [],
            isLoaded: false,
        }
    }

  componentDidMount() {
    const apiUrl = 'https://myGetAllItemsRestApi/Item';
    fetch(apiUrl)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true, items: json,
          })
      });
  }

   
  render() {
    var { isLoaded, items} = this.state;

    if(!isLoaded){
        return <div>Loading API response...</div>;
    }else{
        return(
            
            <div className="Items">
                              
                <br />
                <Table className="Table">
                    <thead>
                        <th>Image</th>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Number</th>
                        <th>Characteristics</th>
                        <th>Full Features</th>
                        <th>
                        {/* For Edit button */} 
                        </th>
                        <th>
                        {/* For Delete button */} 
                        </th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        
                    {items.map(item =>(
                        <tr key={item.itemid}>
                            <td>ImageHolder</td>
                            <td>{item.itemid}</td>
                            <td>{item.item_name}</td>
                            <td>{item.item_price}</td>
                            <td>{item.item_description}</td>
                            <td>{item.item_number}</td>
                            <td>{item.item_characteristics}</td>
                            <td>{item.item_fullfeatures}</td>
                            <td><a href="#">Edit</a></td>
                            <td><a href="#">Delete</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
            </div>
            
        );
    }
  }
}

export default Items;
```

**AddNewItem.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class AddNewItem extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
        <div className="AddNewItem">
            <h1>Add New Item Page</h1>
        </div>);
    }
}

export default AddNewItem;
```

The problem is this,

```
<Link to={"./AddNewItem"} className="btn btn-primary">
    Add Item
</Link>
```

When I click **Add Item**, it only takes me to a blank page (`http://localhost:3000/AddNewItem`) without any text. And I don't see the `<h1>Add New Item Page</h1>`

I know that once the `CREATE` in **CRUD** makes sense, the `UPDATE` and `DELETE` will be easier.
The displaying of all records in table works but the `CREATE-UPDATE-DELETE` isn't

For `UPDATE` and `DELETE`, I know I will have to find a way to pass the `ID` of the selected record.

I'd appreciate any suggestion or comments.

Thank you!

Comment: `I choses ReachJS so I can learn it.`: Do you mean React JS?  Or actually Reach JS?  Edit: question updated (you meant React JS)

Comment: Where did you register the `Route` for `AddNewItem`? It looks like you registered a `Route` for `/products`, but not for whatever you want add new item to be displayed at.

Comment: ```to="/AddNewItem" ``` instead of ```to={"./AddNewItem"}``` and you need to create a route for that to mention a component.

Answer (score 1):

In your `app.js` you need to declare all your routes where you have only declared a few.

Make sure you import the `AddNewItem` file and then once you've made the route the link will work.

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/products" component={Products} />
    <Route path="/AddNewItem" component={AddNewItem} />
    <Route component={NoMatch} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```